# Eigen: What's the output of argmax/argmin when applied to a tensor with duplicate values?

Tags: c++, eigen, tensor

I'm currently utilizing the **Eigen** library within my C++ project, and I'm working with a tensor `tensorA` defined as `{2.02, -4.2, 2.2, 2.2}`. My question pertains to the behavior of the `argmax()` function when applied to this tensor.

Specifically, when I call `argmax()` on `tensorA`, should I expect the result to consistently return the index of the first occurrence of the maximum value, the index of the last occurrence, or is the behavior undetermined and may vary across different environments or versions of Eigen?

Comment: Do the docs say anything about it?

Comment: There are no docs for argmax/min

Comment: Search for argmax at https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/index.php?title=3.4, does that help you?

Comment: There is no documentation for argmax but I found the below "Modify tensor argmin/argmax to always return first occurrence"

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/62280277/2988730

Comment: Guess you can look at source code to determine the behavior, but it won't be guaranteed between versions if it's not documented